# Parceler error passing a Bundle from one Activity to another

Tags: java, android, parcelable, parceler

I decided to use Parceler because it looks like a great library and it is very well supported by the author.  I am using Parceler to wrap an object and pass it to another Activity in a Bundle.  When I attempt to unwrap the object I am getting the error: `android.os.Bundle cannot be cast to org.parceler.ParcelWrapper`

**My FirstActivity code:**

```
 User user = responseData.getUser();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putParcelable("User", Parcels.wrap(user));
    Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("User", bundle);
    startActivity(intent);
```

**My SecondActivity code:**

```
User user = Parcels.unwrap(this.getIntent().getParcelableExtra("User"));
```

I suspect this is just a newbie mistake.  Any constructive assistance is appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need put wrapped object as argument for `putExtra`, not `Bundle`. Here is solution:

```
User user = responseData.getUser();
Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("User", Parcels.wrap(user));
startActivity(intent);
```

On SecondActivity, in its onCreate() method do:

```
User user = (User) Parcels.unwrap(getIntent().getParcelableExtra("User"));
```

Comment: To add, on the receiving side, to unwrap the object:
`User user = (User) Parcels.unwrap(getIntent().getParcelableExtra("user"));`

https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-Parceler#wrapping-up-a-parcel

Answer (score 1):

In **kotlin** you can do it as follows:

```
val user = responseData.getUser()
val bundle = Bundle()
bundle.putParcelable("User", Parcels.wrap(user))
val intent = Intent(this@FirstActivity, SecondActivity::class.java)
intent.putExtra("User", bundle)
startActivity(intent)
```

and in the second activity, where you are going to get the data you can do it as follows:

```
val user: User = Parcels.unwrap(data?.getParcelableExtra("User"))
```

**NOTE:** When using this library you need to use `Parcels.wrap` and`Parcels.unwrap`

Although, I would recommend that if you use `Kotlin` you use `@Parcelize` annotation, since its implementation is very easy and your code is very clean.

If you want to implement `@Parcelize` you can do it as follows:

first, in your **build.gradle** file add the following:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'  

android {
        // ... other codes

        // Add this code 
        androidExtensions {
            experimental = true
        }
    }
```

second, create your data class User with the necessary properties:

```
@Parcelize
data class User(
  val userId: Int,
  val name: String,
  // more properties
) : Parcelable
```